# Thermal expansion at atomic level

Tags: thermodynamics

In my textbook they tried to explain thermal expansion at atomic level with the potential energy curve but it was very complicated.I wish someone could explain it to me:)

A high school level explanation would do.

Comment: Could you add some details? Are you at high school or at the university? What is the book trying to tell you and how? What's wrong/hard to you in the explanation provided in your book?

Comment: I mean in the book it is talking about potential energy curve , the statement was like if the potential energy well is not symmetric and we increase temperature it will oscillate and the average would a little higher than the original and we manifest this as thermal expansion.They didn't even tried to explain it through graph ,I am a high schooler and a simple not very brief explanation would do:)

Comment: See the discussions at [Why solids expand on heating](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/279932/) and [What is Thermal expansion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/332524/).

Comment: I'm imaging an asymmetric vee: [atom]|/ describing the potential energy vs inter atomic separation. As I add water (more energy in the potential well) the center of mass of the water (distance to neighbor) moves away from the [atom].  Pretty killer graphics here.