# What happens to atomic spacing when a spring or solid material is deformed?

Tags: crystals, metals

I am wondering if there is a ever a situation where atomic spacing is decreased when a solid material is deformed? I am aware that atomic layers slide over one another in malleable metals and that this is resisted by crystal grain boundaries. The graph and answer in this SE question    [Why solids expand on heating](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279932/why-solids-expand-on-heating/283367#283367) show that it would take less energy to increase atomic spacing than decrease it.  So does the atomic spacing generally increase when a solid is distorted? Or is there a situation where the normal atomic spacing could be caused to reduce?

Comment: Hydrostatic pressure works just fine. Cooling often does as well.