# How to calculate the expansion of metal on heating?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science

Is there any possible way to calculate the temperature required for a metal to expand or bend, with provided dimensions?

For example, take Mild steel with a length of 100mm, width of 150mm, and thickness of 2.5mm.

I want to know at what temperature(heating) the material starts to expand or bend.

If possible please explain in simple terms.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion

Comment: Note that real behaviors such as bending of an initially flat plate depends strongly on how the plate was processed, including any internal stresses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why solids expand on heating](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279932/why-solids-expand-on-heating)

Answer (score 1):

It expands in all dimension with any increase of temperature, you have to look up the coefficient of expansion for your material. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion